# How can I set Bootstrap modal to bottom-right corner?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to lock a bootstrap modal at bottom right of the window.

What i have is :

HTML

```
<div class="modal custom fade" id="trackModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="trackModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h3 class="getlaid" id="trackModalLabel">Hello</h4>

            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
            <p>TEST</p>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <div class="btnmodal" data-dismiss="modal">Close &#10006;</div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.modal.custom .modal-dialog {
    width:120%;
    position:fixed;
        bottom:0px;
        right:0px;
        margin:0px;

}
```

With this code block I'm not able to display modal at the bottom right of the window and it's keep displaying in the middle of the page. What is wrong here?

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail what is wrong with what you have.  Please be more specific in the issue as just posting code does not tell us what's wrong.

Comment: As explained, the modal is not displaying at bottom right as expected but in the middle of the window.

Comment: Works just fine here...https://jsfiddle.net/wge62q8g/.  If it's showing in the middle of the page, that is due to its parent wrapper which likely has a set width or margin.  The fixed child's 'right: 0; bottom: 0;' is relative to it's parent.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you meant to use 20% instead of 120%?

```
.modal.custom .modal-dialog {
    width:20%;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/6GXNLGHyoW

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me.

```
<div class="modal-dialog position-fixed end-0">
<div class="modal-content position-absolute bottom-0">
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).